# convert “US Number Format To European” in Pivot table excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

My system setting is such all the numbers will be displayed US number format. I have a one off requirement where I need to convert the numbers to European Format. I have found a way to convert the numbers to European format using formula =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(FIXED(B3,2,FALSE),".","$"),",","."),"$",",")

However when I tried create a pivot table the converted numbers are not getting aggregated and value is Zero. I know since my system setting is set up with US number format the numbers are not getting aggregated.To make it work everytime I have to change my system settings to European format and aggregate the data.

It would be of great help if any suggests me any alternative method to change the number format in pivot table.

Thanks,
Ganesh

Comment: Can't you use the format-cells option?

Comment: I tried but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the formatting of the values, not convert your number value into a string.

E.g.: select your cells, press ctrl-1.

Comment: Format the values.... Should I use any specific Custom format to change the numbers from US to European format. I tried few it was not working... It would be great if you could suggest any custom format. May be the custom format is not working since my system setting is US number format. Please advise if I am missing something

Comment: European countries use a comma as decimal separator. Some use a space and some a dot as thousands separator though. I think a space would be safest. You can select the appropriate format from the list of options when pressing ctrl-1 for a selection of cells.